# Is applying Minimax possible with 4 * 4 board Tic Tac Toe or need Alpha-Beta pruning?

Tags: tic-tac-toe, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I've implement a 3 * 3 Tic Tac Toe game in java applying Minimax algorithm only. However, when I change the board size to 4 * 4, the program seems to hang. I wanna ask whether I should apply Minimax with alpha-beta pruning to solve this problem or it is ok with Minimax itself?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with either, but I believe it should work correctly. Just have a look over your code again. Insert debug code to see where it is getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

IF you're trying to do a full depth search, you need to use alpha-beta.  A naive 4 x 4 search tree has 16! or about 21 trillion nodes.  A lot of those nodes need not be searched because the other side refutes an ancestor position by winning on the next move or creating a position that forces a win 2 ply later.  Alpha-beta will let you carve away some of these search spaces without traversing them.